Nothing happens when execution is completed in Google App Scripts
When I execute my script, for some reason it executes but nothing happens on my sheet. I'm trying to pull YouTube Stats automatically to Google Sheets so that I could later set a trigger to update daily.
Here's the code:
// Function to retrieve YouTube channel statistics and update a Google Sheet
function getYouTubeChannelStatistics() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<URL HERE>").getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  
  // Get the data range
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // Loop through each row starting from the second row (assuming the first row is headers)
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    // Assuming the YouTube Channel ID is in the first column
    var channelId = values[i][0];
    
    // Call the YouTube Data API to get channel statistics
    var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels';
    var params = {
      'part': 'statistics',
      'id': channelId,
      'key': '<API KEY HERE>' // Replace with your actual API key
    };
    
    // Make the API request
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl + '?' + Object.keys(params).map(function (key) {
      return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
    }).join('&'));
    
    // Parse the result into JSON
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    // Extract the statistics
    var statistics = result.items[0].statistics;
    
    // Update the spreadsheet with the retrieved data
    // Assuming total subscribers column is the 3rd column
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(statistics.subscriberCount);
    
    // Assuming total views column is the 4th column
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue(statistics.viewCount);
    
    // Assuming total videos column is the 5th column
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue(statistics.videoCount);
  }
}

I went over this plenty of times but I don't seem to remark any error. Might be the fatigue. I would appreciate if someone takes the time to provide me with the fix. Thanks a bunch :-)

Have you enabled the api in the cloud?

I think you need some authorization headers

Are you getting a response

@Cooper Yeah I did enable the API in the cloud, I don't think authorization headers are the problem. I'm not sure what you mean by response... I tried executing the script again and now I'm getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')". I don't get it, it used to execute successfully and doesn't return any result but now there's an error :P

It's one of your variables

what line is the error occuring on.  Do you know how to debug your code?

What type of url are you entering?
Why do you use openByUrl and not openById?

Set the breakpoint to line 37 (sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(statistics.subscriberCount);), start debugging and write what you have in the statistics variable.

Guys I kid you not, everything works perfectly now. I re-ran the code and there's no error appearing, I changed nothing whatsoever. I have no idea how that error appeared. Now I use openByUrl simply because I find it much easier to copy the URL completely than to carefully copy the ID and after having debugged my code at line 37, the statistics variable returned as expected (viewCount; subscriberCount; hiddenSubCount and videoCount). I would love to whatsoever be able to reproduce the bug, so that anyone in the same hole could benefit from the solution, anyhow thank you for your time.

If I were able to reproduce the bug somehow, I will alert it here. Although I don't think it will happen again but who knows!

"I'm getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" This error occurs when an incorrect ID channel is entered.
